# Proper Stack Exchange site for hardware recommendations

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, stackexchange

As title says, is there a Stack Exchange site for hardware recommendations?

Mistakenly, I thought that general (non localized) question about hardware without specific prices and stores would be ok on SU. In fact my question did not ask about a specific product. It would have been perfectly fine being a Community Wiki(before rules were changed).

I missed the change to SU FAQ on Jun 2 of 2010 that prohibited hardware recommendations.

My question was:
https://superuser.com/questions/216367/building-buying-desktop-hardware-for-cs5-illustrator-photoshop-what-to-look-for

I guess, I can go to ARS Technica or Tom's Hardware forum, but I thought the point of Stack Exchange was to combine knowledge not split it.

FAQ does not suggest alternatives, perhaps something should be done to elucidate clueless users like me and save closers some precious time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to ask for computer hardware suggestions?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6166/where-to-ask-for-computer-hardware-suggestions)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current answer would be none. There isn't at this point a Stack Exchange site for shopping recommendations. The main problem is that these recommendations tend to get old very quickly, due to the fast moving industry we are in. However there is a suggestion for one [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20084/technology-recommendations) on Area 51 you can consider supporting.

Comment: Thanks Diago! Appreciate the answer, I will be following the suggested one on Area 51.  I agree that recommendations do tend to get older quite quickly, however that is something to be solved by time/date stamps. Troubleshooting questions also can get out of date, well there really isn't anything truly timeless, if one wants to get philosophical...

Comment: The proposal has now been deleted. That's kind of disappointing.

Comment: A newer proposal has now been in beta for about eight months but is not doing very well: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations